# How to add color on drop down text in Ruby on Rails collection_select

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

```
= f.collection_select :budget_line_id,
                            @budget_lines, :id, :description,
                            { prompt: true },
                            class: 'form-control input-sm form-control-sm'
```

I need to change the text color of elements of this drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't apply a CSS rule for one of your classes you can add an inline style tag to your `collection_select` helper:

```
= f.collection_select :budget_line_id,
                            @budget_lines, :id, :description,
                            { prompt: true },
                            class: "form-control input-sm form-control-sm",
                            style: "select { color: #333333; }"
```

If you have a stylesheet you should be able to add:

```
.form-control select option {
  color: #333333;
}
```

It may require some tweaking either way, depending on the HTML that is being rendered, but one of those should get you close.